# Quality of result set

Tags: here-api

I use the here PlacesServices to retrieve information what's around me. Often I get results that are quite ambiguous / duplicate because outdated data appears to be in the result set that reduces the quality quite significantly. How can we feed back changes to the community or how and when does here get updates for those categories, e.g. restaurants or petrol-stations?
Is there a way to dedup?

This is a good example for 3/6 duplicates (same petrol station) since the chain changed some time ago dependent of the direction on the highway.

```
https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/276u1jne-8c62ebd6159c441eba290df4efdcfd1d;context=Zmxvdy1pZD02ZWQ0YzViNS0wMzgxLTUxZDAtOTg2ZC00NjQ3YTVjNWJhYTJfMTU3NTY2NjU1MTYwM18wXzE1NCZyYW5rPTI

https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/places/276u1jne-3c240a265c6e48d698a400b7d8738202;context=Zmxvdy1pZD02ZWQ0YzViNS0wMzgxLTUxZDAtOTg2ZC00NjQ3YTVjNWJhYTJfMTU3NTY2NjU1MTYwM18wXzE1NCZyYW5rPTQ
```

[3 chains for a single petrol station](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6OoPS.png)

Finally, is there a solution how I'd only obtain those in my travel direction?

```
var query = {"in":  lat +"," + lng +";r="+distance*1000,"cat" : categories +",pretty"};

let entryPoint = H.service.PlacesService.EntryPoint;
    await this.places.request(entryPoint.EXPLORE, query, 
                function(response) {
                    values = response.results.items;
                    }, function(resp) {
                console.log('ERROR: '+resp);
    });
```

Best regards and many thanks in advance
O.

Comment: Can you please share the use-case for Place API or the API that has been used currently.

Comment: Hi, use case is easy, I'd like to retrieve the petrol stations if possible in the driving direction around me as to the bounding box of the viewport. Source code snippet see, edited question

Answer (score 0):

In general the feedback related to HERE Map data can be reported by either the Map Feedback API , the details on the API are available on the [documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/map-feedback/dev_guide/topics/resource-feedback.html) page , or The Online Tool [HERE Map Creator](http://mapcreator.here.com/) could be used.

With respect to retrieving POIs, it is possible to request POIs along the route using the "browse/by-corridor" ([documentation](https://developer.here.com/documentation/places/dev_guide/topics_api/resource-browse-by-corridor.html)) end point where the route shape and a radius could be provided as a corridor. It should be noted however the API does not consider the heading direction of the route and may return POIs on the other side of a road. Example :

https://places.ls.hereapi.com/places/v1/browse/by-corridor?route=[52.5199356,13.3866272|52.5100899,13.2816896|52.4351807,13.1935196|52.4107285,13.1964502|52.38871,13.1557798|52.3727798,13.1491003|52.3737488,13.1154604|52.3875198,13.0872202|52.4029388,13.0706196|52.4105797,13.0755529]&apiKey=API_KEY